# magento 2.1.7 can we give product price based on multiple stores

Tags: magento-2.1.7, stores

As i need to give product price for same product based on multiple stores.
Can we give product price for same product based on multiple stores  in magento 2.1.7

Comment: You can`t give by default to multiple stores (need an extension for that https://bsscommerce.com/magento-multistore-pricing.html) , but creating multiple websites will do the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set price per Store basis.

Go to:

```
System->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog Price Scope.
```

Then in the tab "**Price**", set price scope to "**Website**" instead of global.

Comment: Price is not changing when i swatch stores Shorabh

Comment: The catalog Price Scopee is GLOBAL or By Websites. So you need to create multiples websites and not store view if you want to have different price per products. Moreover, please flush the cache and check if the price reindex has been performed.

Comment: How to get product price for same product based on multiple stores  Franck Garnier..